# WPF Make Column Slide into position XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a wPF application. I have a column that has it's width set to zero at load time. It is bound to a property though & when this value changes to a certain value the width changes to 2*. This all works fine.

What I would like is to add an animation so it appears the column slides onto the grid. It is the column further most right so it would slide from the right of the screen to the left. Reading around it sounds like this is not easily done in just XAML?

***EDIT***

Here is what I have tried so far. The issue is "System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Width' because it is of incompatible type System.Windows.GridLength". Is there where a value converter comes into things?

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition>                            
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderSelected.Name}" Value="Mark">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="2*"/>
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            Duration="0:0:3"
                                            AutoReverse="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>                                  
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Dude... *you* have to have a go first... you can't just come to this site and say *this is what I want you guys to do for me because I can't do it*. From the StackOverflow ['What topics can I ask about here?' help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *3.Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results*.

Comment: I understand you point. I have been reading on the internet to try find a solution. However it appears it is not possible reading other peoples posts. My first few attempts were pretty rubbish and didn't think it would add any value. The edited code above is where I currently am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195722.aspx) to make your life easier. Should do what you're looking for with less fuss. Hope this helps. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `Width` of a `ColumnDefinition` has the type GridLength and therefore it cannot be animated with a DoubleAnimation. The only solution is to define a custom Animation class.

The first Google result I found was this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18379/WPF-Tutorial-Part-2-Writing-a-custom-animation-cla This article gives an example for a Button, but the code should also work on the ColumnDefinition.